# Adding "stretchable" images to and image selected from gallery

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

Im trying to make an app for planning out where you want to put "shelves" on a wall (sounds strange i know ;) )

i have got it so the image is picked from the `UIImagePickerController` then loaded in a new `ViewController` i also have a `button` at the bottom of the `ViewController` that i want to open a list of images to select from that once selected the user can move around then stretch the required size if they don't like, delete and once they are happy i want my second button to save the image and put it into an email ready for sending.

I have looked at a few ways but none of them seem to be "adequate" would be so grateful anyone could suggest any ways or even help me with some code, I'm very new to this and this is my first app.

Im not too sure on the code you'd need to see as none of what is written yet is relevant to this part of the app

This is a 2 part so the first is, what way do i go about it?, the second is what code?

Thanks

Comment: Try using resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode: to convert your images to stretchable ones.

Comment: can i put these images on a UIImageView thats already displaying an image? i only want them to be about 1/12 of the 1st image

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIImage *)GetStreachableImage
```

{

```
UIImage *takephotoButtonImagenormal = [UIImage imageNamed:CHOOSE_TAKE_NORMAL_IMAGE];

UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal1 = [takephotoButtonImagenormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:takephotoButtonImagenormal.size.width/2 topCapHeight:takephotoButtonImagenormal.size.height/2];
    takephotoButtonImagenormal=nil;
     return strechableButtonImageNormal1;
```

}

try this

Comment: where does this get the image from? my images are on a separate view  controller, do i need to turn these images into buttons so that when they are pressed they are sent back to the secondViewController where i want to display them